# Gap when aligning 2 list groups in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center Business1,2 boxes on the same row under What we do..
Plus I want to get rid of that nasty right gap added by Bootstrap3.
I tried many methods but for now none had worked.
My codepen:http://cdpn.io/vFILc
HTML code:

```
![<div class="slide1">
          <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="page-header">
                 <h2 class="skills " style="font-family: Arial">What we do</h2>
                </div> 
               </div> 
             </div>
           </div>
         </div><!--end slide1 --> 
         <article class="container">
            <div class="row" id="boxes">
             <section class="col-sm-6" id="first-section">
              <div class="list-group" id="business1">
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
                      Business1
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Construction</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Design</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Etc</a>
              </div> 
             </section>
             <section class="col-sm-6" id="second-section">
               <div class="list-group" id="business2">
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
                     Business2
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Planning</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Outsourcing</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Hr</a>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div><!--end row-->
        </article>][1]



  CSS:
    #boxes{margin:0 auto;}
    #business1{width: 250px;}
    #business2{width:250px;}
```

Comment: .list-group {
    margin: auto;
} ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `text-center` class

**Bootply** :http://www.bootply.com/128932

**HTML** :

```
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">   <!-- HERE -->
            <div class="page-header">
             <h2 class="skills " style="font-family: Arial">What we do</h2>
            </div> 
           </div> 
         </div>
       </div>
```

**UPDATE** :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/128934

**Just add css** :

```
.list-group{
     width:150px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
  }
```

**UPDATE AGAIN** :

Just change the col-6 to what you want

For exemple : col-3 :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/128937

Comment: The problem is when I add width to box1,2. I don't want to stretch the whole width of the row I want them smaller..When I add width the boxes looses their alignment..I want them to have let's say 200px each box.Both boxes looses their alignment when I do that.

Comment: Is there a way to remove some space between the 2 boxes because It's a lot of white space?

Comment: @Lucas Don't forget to close the topic in accepting the answer when you'll be sure that it works...